# containerd multiline logs parsing with fluentbit

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, fluent-bit, containerd

After shifting from Docker to containerd as docker engine used by our kubernetes, we are not able to show the multiline logs in a proper way by our visualization app (Grafana) as some details prepended to the container/pod logs by the containerd itself (i.e. timestamp, stream & log severity to be specific it is appending something like the following and as shown in the below sample: **2022-07-25T06:43:17.20958947Z stdout F**  ) which make some confusion for the developers and the application owners.

I am showing here a dummy sample of the logs generated by the application and how it got printed in the nodes of kuberenetes'nodes after containerd prepended the mentioned details.

The following logs generated by the application (kubectl logs ):

```
2022-07-25T06:43:17,309ESC[0;39m dummy-[txtThreadPool-2] ESC[39mDEBUGESC[0;39m
  ESC[36mcom.pkg.sample.ComponentESC[0;39m - Process message meta {
  timestamp: 1658731397308720468
  version {
      major: 1
      minor: 0
      patch: 0
  }
}
```

when I check the logs in the filesystem (/var/log/container/ABCXYZ.log) :

```
2022-07-25T06:43:17.20958947Z stdout F 2022-07-25T06:43:17,309ESC[0;39m dummy-[txtThreadPool-2]
ESC[39mDEBUGESC[0;39m
ESC[36mcom.pkg.sample.ComponentESC[0;39m - Process message meta {
2022-07-25T06:43:17.20958947Z stdout F timestamp: 1658731449723010774
2022-07-25T06:43:17.209593379Z stdout F version {
2022-07-25T06:43:17.209595933Z stdout F major: 14
2022-07-25T06:43:17.209598466Z stdout F minor: 0
2022-07-25T06:43:17.209600712Z stdout F patch: 0
2022-07-25T06:43:17.209602926Z stdout F }
2022-07-25T06:43:17.209605099Z stdout F }
```

I am able to parse the multiline logs with fluentbit but the problem is I am not able to remove the details injected by containerd ( >> 2022-07-25T06:43:17.209605099Z stdout F .......). So is there anyway to configure containerd to not prepend these details somehow in the logs and print them as they are generated from the application/container ?

On the other hand is there any plugin to remove such details from fluentbit side .. as per the existing [plugins](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/concepts/data-pipeline) none of them can manipulate or change the logs (which is logical  as the log agent should not do any change on the logs).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the workaround I followed to show the multiline log lines in Grafana by applying extra fluentbit filters and multiline parser.

1- First I receive the stream by tail input which parse it by a multiline parser (multilineKubeParser).

2- Then another filter will intercept the stream to do further processing by a regex parser (kubeParser).

3- After that another filter will remove the details added by the containerd by a lua parser ().

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |-
    [SERVICE]
        HTTP_Server    On
        HTTP_Listen    0.0.0.0
        HTTP_PORT      2020
        Flush          1
        Daemon         Off
        Log_Level      warn
        Parsers_File   parsers.conf
    [INPUT]
        Name           tail
        Tag            kube.*
        Path           /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.Parser         multilineKubeParser
        Exclude_Path   /var/log/containers/*_ABC-logging_*.log
        DB             /run/fluent-bit/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit  5MB
    [FILTER]
        Name           kubernetes
        Match          kube.*
        Kube_URL       https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Merge_Log On
        Merge_Parser   kubeParser
        K8S-Logging.Parser Off
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
    [FILTER]
        Name           lua
        Match          kube.*
        call remove_dummy
        Script filters.lua
    [Output]
        Name grafana-loki
        Match kube.*
        Url http://loki:3100/api/prom/push
        TenantID ""
        BatchWait 1
        BatchSize 1048576
        Labels {job="fluent-bit"}
        RemoveKeys kubernetes
        AutoKubernetesLabels false
        LabelMapPath /fluent-bit/etc/labelmap.json
        LineFormat json
        LogLevel warn
  labelmap.json: |-
    {
      "kubernetes": {
        "container_name": "container",
        "host": "node",
        "labels": {
          "app": "app",
          "release": "release"
        },
        "namespace_name": "namespace",
        "pod_name": "instance"
      },
      "stream": "stream"
    }
  parsers.conf: |-
    [PARSER]
        Name        kubeParser
        Format      regex
        Regex       /^([^ ]*).* (?<timeStamp>[^a].*) ([^ ].*)\[(?<requestId>[^\]]*)\] (?<severity>[^ ]*) (?<message>[^ ].*)$/
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
        Time_Keep   On
        Time_Offset +0200
    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name          multilineKubeParser
        type          regex
        flush_timeout 1000           
        rule      "start_state"   "/[^ ]* stdout .\s+\W*\w+\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d,\d\d\d.*$/"  "cont"
        rule      "cont"          "/[^ ]* stdout .\s+(?!\W+\w+\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d,\d\d\d).*$/"   "cont"

  filters.lua: |-

    function remove_dummy(tag, timestamp, record)
       new_log=string.gsub(record["log"],"%d+-%d+-%d+T%d+:%d+:%d+.%d+Z%sstdout%sF%s","")
       new_record=record
       new_record["log"]=new_log
       return 2, timestamp, new_record
    end
```

As I mentioned this is a workaround till I can find any other/better solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the configuration options for `containerd`, it appears there's no way to configure logging in any way. You can see the config doc [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/man/containerd-config.toml.5.md).

Also, I checked at the logging code inside `containerd` and it appears this is prepended to the logs as they are redirected from the `stdout` of the container. You can see that the testcase [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/78cd9d3b6b4c1a8d977a9ee695328f4c51a304d0/pkg/cri/io/logger_test.go#L239) checks for appropriate fields by "splitting" the log line received. It checks for a `tag` and a `stream` entry prepended to the `content` of the log. I suppose that's the way logs are processed in `containerd`.

The best thing to do would be to open an [issue](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues) in the project with your design requirement and perhaps the team can develop configurable `stdout` redirection for you.

Comment: You are right. I checked the containerd configurations and no way to do this from containerd side and I already opened a [discussion ](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/discussions/7209#discussioncomment-3232595) in the containerd project before raising the case here to find anyone who has the same case and did any workaround either in containerd or fluentbut. Anyway thanks for your help !

Comment: happy to help! I wish it gets resolved soon :) What you mention appears to be a genuine use-case, which the community might be interested in implementing.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. They use a custom regex to capture the message log and the rest of the info in the logs and then use lift in the nest filter to flatten the json.
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentbit-containerd-cri-o-json-log

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33269042)

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue.

I changed my parser from Docker to "cri" in my input plugin and
then added the below filter and it works as before

```
  [FILTER]
      Name                        modify
      Match                       kube.*
      Rename                      message log
```